# Spark - Adding file is not working in cluster mode

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

I am using Spark version `1.3.1` as cluster. I want to pipe data into a python script in scala spark context. I found something to do that which is adding python files in spark context. This works properly with standalone mode of spark. But it is not working for cluster.

It is supposed to add that python file into other nodes as well as master. But it does not. I checked `tmp` folder to see added files. Only master has that file. What is wrong with it? is it buggy or is there something I miss.

```scala
scala> import org.apache.spark.SparkFiles

scala> var script_file = "/home/hdfs/my_script.py"
scala> var script_name = "my_script 1"
scala>
scala> sc.addFile(script_file)
16/09/26 07:04:39 INFO Utils: Copying /home/hdfs/my_script.py to /tmp/spark-d4dd61c2-f422-4846-8486-5705ee54e320/userFiles-c8a810d7-3ef8-43bc-a346-4822c8b817e7/my_script.py
16/09/26 07:04:39 INFO SparkContext: Added file /home/hdfs/my_script.py at http://x.x.x.x:39017/files/my_script.py with timestamp 1474873479690
scala>
scala> val ipData = sc.parallelize(List("test data 1","test data 2"))


scala> val opData = ipData.pipe(SparkFiles.get(script_name))
scala> opData.foreach(println)
```

Output says no such file on other nodes;

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 30 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 30.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 60, my_other_node_1): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/spark-d4dd61c2-f422-4846-8486-5705ee54e320/userFiles-c8a810d7-3ef8-43bc-a346-4822c8b817e7/my_script.py": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Comment: Not 100% but I believe it might be because you're running in cluster mode. The master of the cluster adds the file to its own machine but then you're running a spark task which runs on the workers.

Comment: Yes you are right, I know that but is it supposed to add the file into worker nodes too?

Comment: @AhmetDAL : Did you try setting master as cluster URL when you run it on cluster?

Comment: I am deploying my application to yarn which means, using yarn-client